# Why does a stray period cause an error I associate with mismatched parens?

Tags: list, syntax

A typo that changed `(foo)` to `(foo . )` in my `.init` file caused an `Invalid read syntax: )` error.

**I get why it's a syntax error. But why *this* error?**  I thought this error message reliably reflected mismatched parentheses, and I spent ages barking up the wrong tree. What am I misunderstanding? Is there something about the elisp parser that makes a stray `.` look like an extra `)` to it? What other kinds of syntax error show up this way?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Cool — your tags work for me, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The period is part of the read syntax for a cons. `(a b)` is a list, while `(a . b)` is a cons. The difference is that the list is made of two conses, so the first is equivalent to `(a . (b . nil))`. The error message is telling you that it saw a `)` that it did not expect. It expected to see anything other than a `)`, because it was expecting to read a new object rather than the end of an existing one.